# How to retrieve a element by class name by its position

Tags: jquery, classname

How do you translate the following into jQuery?

```
document.getElementsByClassName('x')[5]
```

`$('.x')[5]` does not seem to work. i could go with a

```
$('.x').each(){function(i){ if(i==5) return $(this) })
```

but there must be an easier inline way.

Comment: `$('.x')[5]` does in fact work, but it gives you the actual DOM element, not a jQuery object. Theoretically, you could use `$($('.x')[5])` but that’s a very bad idea. Use `$('.x:eq(5)')` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
$('.x:eq(5)');
```